# why getAdapterPosition return wrong value, when I make ViewHolder as class member of RecyclerView.Adapter

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I got a weird problem. I did search on internet, but it looks no same problems.

In FruitAdapter.java,if I make **ViewHolder** be class member of **RecyclerView**, then **getAdapterPosition** will return wrong value!!!.

if I make ViewHolder as RecyclerView'  function local variable, NO error. the ViewHolder is constructed at same place,in onCreateViewHolder,

In FruitAdapter.java,

Here is the code.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.recyclerviewtest;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private List<String> fruitList = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initFruits();
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        LinearLayoutManager linerLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linerLayoutManager);
        FruitAdapter adapter = new FruitAdapter(fruitList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void initFruits() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

            fruitList.add("apple");
            fruitList.add("banana");
            fruitList.add("orange");
            fruitList.add("watermelon");
            fruitList.add("pear");

           }
    }
}
```

FruitAdapter.java

```
package com.example.recyclerviewtest;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;

public class FruitAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FruitAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    private List<String> mFruitList;


    **//if I use below, I got the Problem
    //ViewHolder holder;**

    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        View fruitView;

        TextView fruitName;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            fruitView = view;

            fruitName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fruitItemName);
        }
    }

    public FruitAdapter(List<String> fruitList) {
        mFruitList = fruitList;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fruit_item, parent, false);

        //this works, but if holder is class member,then problems happen
        final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
        //holder = new ViewHolder(view);

        holder.fruitView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int position = holder.getAdapterPosition();
                String fruit = mFruitList.get(position);
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "you clicked view " + fruit, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String fruit = mFruitList.get(position);
        holder.fruitName.setText(fruit);
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mFruitList.size();
    }

}
```

Comment: Do the click logic either in your onBindViewHolder or in the ViewHolder itself not in the onCreateViewHolder function, that is where they create the viewHolder but it doesn't bind the items to the RecyclerView until you've finished looping through the items in onBindViewHolder, I would read up on these methods and why they exist and you'll soon sort your problem out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onCreateViewHolder` is being called when there is not any `ViewHolder` in the pool of `ViewHolder`s, so the `RecyclerView` has to create a new one.

Assume you have 100 items in the list and only 10 are displayed at a time on the screen. When you have scrolled to the e.g. 15th item in the list, the top `ViewHolder`s would be recycled and placed to the pool as soon as they are no longer visible. But, new items should become visible, so `RecyclerView` fetches new `ViewHolder` from the pool for each item and calls `onBindViewHolder()`. **NOTE**, `onCreateViewHolder` won't be called anymore, because it is already created and present in the pool.

When you keep a reference to the `ViewHolder` that you have created in `onCreateViewHolder`, you keep a reference to a `ViewHolder` which is not what you want. In this example, it would be let's say 11. So, when you scroll to 80th item, you still will get 11 as a `getAdapterPosition()` value.

Additionally, `onCreateViewHolder()` method is, as the name suggests, for creating a `ViewHolder`, nothing more. For setting up the view there is `onBindViewHolder()`. Thus, perform your setup logic (e.g. `setOnClickListener()`) from `onBindViewHolder()` callback.

Comment: Hi,azizbekian,thanks for your rapid reply. but I still have some confusion.your point is the class member reference make creating new view holder is distrubed somehow? I think that when a ViewHolder  is created and return, there will maybe two references, one is the class member, anthoer is something in RecyclerView. when another ViewHolder   is created, the previous ViewHolder  then will have one reference. could you give some further explanation? thanks a lot.

Comment: for my understanding, the difference between class member and function variable is the life, return class member will keep a reference on it. so it may generate memory leak, but why function go wrong. I check documents and I don't find any Warning/error like not return class member.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks,azizbekian& Bradley Wilson,

you are correct. after I put onclick logic in onBindViewHolder,the weird thing gone.

Quote to Bradley Wilson's comment " onCreateViewHolder is where they create the viewHolder but it doesn't bind the items to the RecyclerView until you've finished looping through the items in onBindViewHolder, "

but one thins still pretty weird,why function local variable works.